# using a nested function in clojure

Tags: clojure, nested-loops

I am trying to make a nested function that should be run recursively in Clojure in order to collect some information.
I have seen some techniques such as fn, loop, doseq but I am not good with them for now.

First let me explain why I want to use a recursive funtion: 
I have a class and this class include 2 methods itself, these methods are namely getLeft() and getRight(), plus the return type of the methods are also a class. I do want simply traverse all getLeft and getRight methods in order to get the proper number from them.

Just to be clear, I put a schema:

My Main Class:

```
                     +-- getRight(): class  - getLeft/getRight
++ getLeft(): class ---  
                     +-- getLeft((): class  - getLeft/getRight
                     +-- getRight(): class  - getLeft/getRight
++ getRight() :class
                     +-- getLeft((): class  - getLeft/getRight
```

I also made a function called "loopingP" but when I add this func to my another function, it gives an error.
Error: NullPointerException   org.mtrcclojure.demo/loopingP (NO_SOURCE_FILE:4)

```
     (defn loopingP [points]
       (if (= (getKind points) 5)
        ( (loopingP (getRight points)) (loopingP (getLeft points)))
       (if (= (getKind points) 3) (println "Yep"))))
```

How can I properly use a nested function in Clojure for my purpose?
Thanks in advance!

Solution is: putting a []

```
(defn loopingP [points]
       (if (= (getKind points) 5)
        [ (loopingP (getRight points)) (loopingP (getLeft points))]
       (if (= (getKind points) 3) (println "Yep"))))
```

Comment: What is `points` in your example?

Comment: points means a poincut class that is included in ajdt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extraneous set of parenthesis around your recursion case - perhaps you meant to group the getRight and getLeft calls into a pair? the base case always returns nil (either from the false branch of the if, or from the println) so the leftmost recursion gets applied, and thus you call nil as a function (leading to a NullPointerException).

Comment: if I eliminate one nested call from the loopingP , the function receives me a string "Yep". But How can I use two nested call for left and right?

Comment: If you were trying to build a tuple with two elements, you can use the vector literal `[(loopingP (getRight points)) (loopingP (getLeft points))]`.

Comment: yes exactly I did like your answer @juan.facorro and I have received now this output :  [[5 _0] nil] nil]. how can I split them?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean by splitting them. What is the final result you hope to get?

Comment: Onw way to do it is `flatten`ing the result and then `filter`ing non nil elements: `(->> points loopingP flatten (filter identity))`.